# Помогите новичку с задачей

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Подскажите как можно решить такую задачу:
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при активном пункте подменю все меню было открыто. Идея показана на скриншоте  [image: скриншот]

Получается, что когда посетитель на странице "history" чтобы меню оставалось открыто до тех пор пока он не перейдет на другую страницу. Можно ли такое сделать каким-то плагином в WordPress или как-то по другому?
Спасибо!

Comment: Функция, которая его закрывает, должна проверять - `if (любой из пунктов выбран) return;`

Comment: Направление понял. Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: wp должно добавить класс к родителю, к примеру .active и через css прописать открытие